# Does the Deathstar still have it's "One shot one kill" feature?

Tags: world-of-tanks

I am currently grinding my way up the British Tank Destroyer Line, and I am at Tier 7 (AT 7 Tank Destroyer.) I am contemplating whether I should continue grinding the line, or abandon it and move onto a heavy tank line. I have seen some videos on YouTube, some say it is still worth it after the latest update, others are saying it got hit with the Nerf bat and has become nothing more than a horizontal artillery, thus making it not worth the grind.

Long story short, does the Deathstar still have it's "One shot one kill" feature or would I be better off playing in the KV-2?

Thanks Again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tier 10 Deathstar has its worth, though it is a completely different playstyle with its predecessors. it'd take sometime to get used to the long reload when you've been getting rapid firing guns since tier 5, though the high alpha of the Deathstar still stands its ground as a formidable opponent

KV2 and deathstar are different although the soviet ht has the 152mm howitzer. KV2 is considered the tier-less tank (i would say) in world of tanks as with careful positioning and playing the fire support role when you're bottom tier, you can still dish out quite some punishment. Basically a walking artillery, much like the t49.

TLDR: yes, deathstar is worth the grind, high penetration （AP 1150dmg /310pen prem HE 1750dmg /230pen) and good alpha is always a good combination.

have fun grinding the AT-7 :D